# Maximize $P=xy^2+yz^2+zx^2+xyz$ if $(x^2+y^2)(y^2+z^2)(z^2+x^2)=2$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, rearrangement-inequality, schur-inequality

If $x,y,z\ge 0: (x^2+y^2)(y^2+z^2)(z^2+x^2)=2.$ Find the maximum $$P=xy^2+yz^2+zx^2+xyz$$

I guess equality occurs when $x=y=z$ so I tried to prove homogenizing inequality $$xy^2+yz^2+zx^2+xyz \le \sqrt{2(x^2+y^2)(y^2+z^2)(z^2+x^2)}$$
Now, by well-known result $xy^2+yz^2+zx^2+xyz \le\dfrac{4}{27}(x+y+z)^3,$ we just need to prove $$\dfrac{4}{27}(x+y+z)^3\le \sqrt{2(x^2+y^2)(y^2+z^2)(z^2+x^2)} $$ It is equivalent to $$\dfrac{8}{729}(x+y+z)^6\le(x^2+y^2)(y^2+z^2)(z^2+x^2) \tag{1}$$
I am stuck to continue.

Hope you can help me prove $(1)$

Also, I am looking for other proofs. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: If you substitute $y=z=x$ in the equality constraint, you end up with $8x^2=2$ which means that $x=y=z=\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Alternative proof.**

WLOG, assume that $(x-y)(z-y)\le 0.$ It implies
\begin{align*}
xy^2+yz^2+zx^2+xyz&=yx^2+yz^2+2xyz+x(x-y)(z-y)\\&\le yx^2+2xyz+yz^2\\&= y(x+z)^2
\end{align*}
By using CBS inequality
\begin{align*}
y(x+z)^2&=(x+z)(yx+yz)\\&\le \sqrt{2(x^2+z^2)}.\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)(z^2+y^2)}\\&=\sqrt{2(x^2+z^2)(x^2+y^2)(z^2+y^2)}.
\end{align*}
The desired follows.

Answer (score 1):

Another way.

Let $\{x,y,z\}=\{a,b,c\},$ where $a\geq b\geq c$.

Thus, by Rearrangement and C-S twice we obtain:
$$xy^2+yz^2+zx^2+xyz=xy\cdot y+yz\cdot z+zx\cdot x+abc\leq $$
$$\leq ab\cdot a+bc\cdot c+ac\cdot b+abc=b(a+c)^2=$$
$$=\sqrt{b^2(a+c)^4}\leq\sqrt{(ab+bc)^2\cdot2(a^2+c^2)}\leq\sqrt{2(a^2+b^2)(b^2+c^2)(a^2+c^2)}=2.$$
The equality occurs for $x=y=z,$ which says that we got a maximal value.

Comment: I think we have $ac\geq bc$. Then, how the rearrangement method works?

Comment: @Reza Rajaei Rearrangement in our case it's the following. If $p\geq q\geq r$ and $u\geq v\geq w$ so $pu+qv+rw$ is a greatest. We know that $a\geq b\geq c$ and $ab\geq ac\geq bc$, Thus, $a\cdot ab+b\cdot ac+c\cdot bc$ is a greatest. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality

Comment: I see. But it seems you have already assumed that $x \geq y \geq z.$

Comment: @Reza Rajaei Really? See please better my solution. $(a,b,c)$ is a permutation of $(x,y,z)$ such that $a\geq b\geq c$.

Comment: I had got confused with the order. Now, everything is fine. Nice solution! [+1]

Comment: +1, very nice and short!

Answer (score 1):

**Proof.**

We will prove $$xy^2+yz^2+zx^2+xyz\le \sqrt{2(x^2+y^2)(y^2+z^2)(z^2+x^2)}.\tag{*}$$
By using CBS inequality, $$xy^2+yz^2+zx^2=xy.y+yz.z+zx.x+xyz\le \sqrt{(x^2+y^2+z^2)(x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2x^2)}.$$
Also by AM-GM $$xy^2+yz^2+zx^2\ge 3xyz \implies xyz+xy^2+yz^2+zx^2\le \frac{4(xy^2+yz^2+zx^2)}{3}.$$
Id est, it is enough to prove $$\frac{4}{3}\sqrt{(x^2+y^2+z^2)(x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2x^2)} \le \sqrt{2(x^2+y^2)(y^2+z^2)(z^2+x^2)},$$or $$9(x^2+y^2)(y^2+z^2)(z^2+x^2)\ge 8(x^2+y^2+z^2)(x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2x^2).$$
The last inequality is a well- known result which $$\iff x^2(y^2-z^2)^2+y^2(z^2-x^2)^2+z^2(x^2-y^2)^2\ge 0.$$

Hence, $(*)$ is proven. We got that maximal is equal to $2$ when $x=y=z=\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}}.$

Comment: Thank you for editing @Michael Rozenberg !

Comment: You are welcome. Nice solution!

Answer (score 0):

After squaring we need to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}(2x^4y^2+x^4z^2-2x^3y^2z-2x^3z^2y+x^2y^2z^2)\geq0,$$ which is true by AM-GM, Schur and AM-GM again:
$$\sum_{cyc}(2x^4y^2+x^4z^2-2x^3y^2z-2x^3z^2y+x^2y^2z^2)\geq$$
$$\geq\sum_{cyc}(2x^3y^3+x^4y^2-2x^3y^2z-2x^3z^2y+x^2y^2z^2)=$$
$$=2\sum_{cyc}(x^3y^3-x^3y^2x-x^3z^2y+x^2y^2z^2)+\sum_{cyc}(x^4y^2-x^2y^2z^2)\geq0.$$
Thus, $P\leq2.$

The equality occurs for $x=y=z,$ which says that we got a maximal value.